# Why is my container argument not working for wp_nav_menu()

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes

The following code outputs a menu but the container `<nav>` tag is missing.

```
$menu_settings = array(
    'menu' => 'Packages',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'menu',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true,
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after' => '',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0,
    'walker' => '',
    'theme_location' => 'primary' );

?>

      <?php wp_nav_menu( $menu_settings ); ?>
```

These are registered in functions.php:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
 'primary' => __( 'Packages Menu', 'nameoftheme'),
 'secondary' => __( 'Services Menu', 'nameoftheme' ),
) );
```

Only a `<ul>` with list items is rendered. List items are also not wrapped.

Comment: Please properly indent your code. On smaller screens most of your code is out of bounds and thus unreadable :-)

Comment: Done. Should point out though that less reasonable developers might balk at being told to 'indent properly' :-)

Comment: That is true, but again it is up to them if they want to be helped. Most users like me are on small screen devices like mobile phones, and if code is not properly indented or added, we can't read it and therefor just ignore the question. As a developer you should know just how frustrating it is to read code and debugging it if it has format issues. :-) This is just my thoughts and a tip. It is true, the readability of a question does influence the amount of positive feedback you get back

Comment: Code seems to be ok. Just tried it out and it does spit out the nav container, and wrapped up items as well.

Comment: Does this still happen, after you [disabled all plugins and switched to one of the Twenty* themes?](http://i.imgur.com/wScmw.png) Please follow the linked process to identify the conflicting plugin or theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am using the roots theme framework, [this line](https://github.com/roots/roots/blob/master/lib/nav.php#L79) removes the container argument:

```
function roots_nav_menu_args($args = '') {
  $roots_nav_menu_args = array();
  $roots_nav_menu_args['container'] = false;
  if (!$args['items_wrap']) {
    $roots_nav_menu_args['items_wrap'] = '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';
  }
  if (!$args['depth']) {
    $roots_nav_menu_args['depth'] = 2;
  }
  return array_merge($args, $roots_nav_menu_args);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'roots_nav_menu_args');
```

Comment: This can now be found in Soil: `add_theme_support('soil-nav-walker');`